# UWP Calendar Date Picker Control

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, datepicker, uwp, calendar

How can we Decrease the Font Size and Size of the UWP Calendar Date Picker Control?
I want to decrease the size of the Calendar Popup but It's not working and also the Font size of dates is not getting Changed even after changing the value for font size property of the Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's is not possible to change the size of CalendarDatePicker in UWP apps as already described by documentation for size  as follows:

Several of the FrameworkElement derived types are also derived from Shape. Not all of the Shape classes use Height or Width to specify their appearance, and instead use specific properties that might define a set of points. In this case a Height or Width is calculated, but is not typically set directly.

Comment: Is there any Workaround for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, generally UWP controls are designed as a responsive app but may be some third party providers like Syncfuson have such control but I've not used it for this purpose.